# access GPSD port 2947 over network

Tags: systemd, gpsd

Have a RPI2 with latest Jessie Lite Raspbian Jan 2017 with Adafruit Ultimate GPS hat and PPS using info from a post at digitalbarbedwire.com. Easy setup and PPS and all gps commands work great locally.

I am trying to get gpsd to accept incoming requests over the network on port 2947 to export position info (OpenCPN). I edited /etc/default/gpsd to add the -G option GPSD_OPTIONS="-n -G" but external requests are not being allowed. If I stop gpsd (sudo service stop gpsd), and invoke gps in the foreground (/usr/sbin/gpsd -N -n -G /dev/ttyAMA0 /dev/pps0, all works fine! So I am guessing there is a permissions problem starting the gpsd as a daemon, but I haven't figured it out yet.  Drivings me nuts!

Any suggestions?

Relevant files:

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/gpsd.socket
[Unit]
Description=GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/gpsd.sock
ListenStream=[::1]:2947
ListenStream=0.0.0.1:2947
SocketMode=0600

[Install]
WantedBy=socket

$ cat /etc/default/gpsd
# Default settings for the gpsd init script and the hotplug wrapper.

# Start the gpsd daemon automatically at boot time
START_DAEMON="true"

# Use USB hotplugging to add new USB devices automatically to the daemon
USBAUTO="true"


# Devices gpsd should collect to at boot time.
# They need to be read/writeable, either by user gpsd or the group dialout.
DEVICES="/dev/ttyAMA0 /dev/pps0"

# Other options you want to pass to gpsd
GPSD_OPTIONS="-n"

$ cat /lib/systemd/system/gpsd.service
[Unit]
Description=GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon
Requires=gpsd.socket
# Needed with chrony SOCK refclock
After=chronyd.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/gpsd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/gpsd -N -G $GPSD_OPTIONS $DEVICES

[Install]
Also=gpsd.socket
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Gpsd is not actually listening on port 2947, systemd is. By default in Debian this is local only. When a request comes in systemd starts gpsd, if necessary, and redirects future requests to the daemon. So giving gpsd the -G parameter will not actually change anything.

You need to add an override for the systemd gpsd.socket unit, and tell it to listen on all addresses:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/gpsd.socket.d/socket.conf
[Socket]
# First blank ListenStream clears the system defaults
ListenStream=
ListenStream=2947
ListenStream=/var/run/gpsd.sock
```

Best practice is to put this override file in /etc/systemd/, and not to edit the unit files in /lib/systemd/.

Documentation on the systemd.socket syntax: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html

Comment: I had to struggle for ~8 hours only to find out that the order of `ListenStream`s matters! And it actually should be vice versa: the `/var/run/gpsd.sock` unix socket should be specified first after clearing, because it is the default way to comunicate for the systemd socket processes. The correct order is `ListenStream=
ListenStream=/var/run/gpsd.sock
ListenStream=2947`

Comment: Thank you Dima for the last piece of the puzzle!

Answer (score 2):

Linux Mint 19, I had to replace 127.0.0.1 with 0.0.0.0, then I could share GPS data on LAN

```
#/lib/systemd/system/gpsd.socket/gpsd.socket

[Unit]
Description=GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/gpsd.sock
ListenStream=[::1]:2947
#ListenStream=127.0.0.1:2947
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:2947
SocketMode=0600

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to do a terminal-less SSH session with port forwarding.

For example, let's say you have PC1 running a gpsd service (either via systemd or stand-alone).

From PC2, you can do this:

```
ssh -N -L 2947:localhost:2947 user@PC1
```

The -N flag prevents an actual terminal session (no commands executed).
The -L flag means forward port 2947 to localhost 2947.

Now, ssh will not auto-reconnect if for some reason the session is lost or terminated.  The work around is to install [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/), available in most linux distro repositories.

You can then use autossh like so:

```
autossh -N -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -L 2947:localhost:2947 user@PC1
```

If it works, add -f to let autossh go in background mode.

You can easily run autossh from rc.local or a systemd unit.  Doing it this ways means you only have to allow SSH port in (22) and are now passing the gps info via a secure encrypted connection, something that a gpsd socket session alone can't do. Obviously, it helps if you have a key pair setup between PC1 and PC2 as you won't need a password.

You can run on PC2 any of the gpsd tools that come with it as it will appear local to it.  API calls from scripts/programs will also work as if port 2947 was actually running gpsd locally.

[Look here for more detail on how to use autossh](https://www.everythingcli.org/ssh-tunnelling-for-fun-and-profit-autossh/).

Answer (score 1):

After running down all the suggestions including the above, I ended up just following the instructions on the [troubleshooting page for gpsd in gitlab](https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/troubleshooting.html), in the last section called "Real World Example". That's the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install socat
and use this command:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:2948,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:localhost:2947
```

And use port 2948 over network
You can add this in crontab